# Java 1.7_u51 Debugging Applets launched by a web page using Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging, applet

I am trying to debug an `applet` using eclipse with the latest `JDK (1.7_51)`. I have set the JVM parameters through Java Control Panel as

```
-Djava.compiler=NONE -Xnoagent -Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,address=8091,server=y,suspend=y
```

In Java Console I can see that the parameters are being passed and are passed correctly. However,when I try to connect to the `port 8091` using Eclipse debugging as a Remote Java Application, Host is localhost, Standard Socket Attach and port 8091, it fails to connect to the JVM. I have ensured that port 8091 is not in use.

I have even tried

```
-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,address=8091,server=y,suspend=y
```

without any success. Through all these trials, I have been checking the ports in use through

```
netstat -lntu
```

to see if port 8091 ever goes in a `LISTEN` mode but it never does so no wonder Eclipse cannot connect. My question is has anyone successfully debugged Applets with Eclipse using the newest JDK release. If so, how?

Comment: Maybe this will help  http://sharingtechexperiencies.blogspot.com/2013/05/remote-debugging-applet-with-eclipse.html  - looks like some of their parm values are different - server=n for example

Comment: Works for me with 1.7_65, although I have suspend=n.

Answer (score 0):

Before java 1.7_XXX, I always debug the applets as you do (with same configuration). Since this version was released I must change my debug configuration in order to debug an applet. So if you want to debug applet with 1.7_0.51 your java control panel configuration must looks like:

```
-Djava.compiler=NONE -Xnoagent -Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_shmem,address=8000,server=y,suspend=n
```

In eclipse debug configuration, choose remote java application and as connection type select "Standard(Socket Listen)" instead of "Standard(Socket attach) and set the port.

Hope this helps,

Answer (score 0):

This is a painful regression introduced in Java 7, to the best of my understanding the fix is only in Java 8... however, some back-porting was done to build ~60... though I'm not sure that all issues were fixed or maybe only partial back-porting took place...requires verification...

here it is: http://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=8016005